# How to create a forecast object in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I have wrote a function that forecasts a time series object using different forecast methods like `forecast::nnetar`, `forecast::tbats`, `forecast::Arima` and `forecast::ets`.
I know that `forecastHybrid::hybridModel` function is doing this, I just wanted to create something more customized. So I am now returning a list with `result$mean`, `result$error` and `result$fit`. I want to use accuracy or plot function like forecast object. Is there a easy way to do that? or is it too complicated?

EDIT: About the function, it takes a `ts` object, an arima model-that I found by taking differences and checking ACF-PACF graphs- and a horizon to be forecasted.  It applies `nnetar`, `ets`, `tbats` and my arima model.
It combines their fits and forecasts and create a new fit values and forecast values.
It returns a list object with forecasted values as `result$mean` (this is also same in forecast objects), fitted values as `result$fit` and errors as `result$error`.
Now with that returned object, I cant automate some series of works like having accuracy, making plots etc. So I want to return a forecast object if it is possible. that is what it is.

Comment: Could you show a reproducible example of the code you're using and/or the object you're returning, and a specific example of what you want to do with it (e.g. what kind of plot)?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, ...not to mention unclear about exactly what is expected from data that is not presented.

Comment: edited. @DavidRobinson

Comment: All the different methods in forecast return different classes of output, for example `class(nnetar(lynx)) == "nnetar")`. You need to add a new method to `plot` for it to work with your object. If your object contains all the necessary pieces for `accuracy`, just edit the `accuracy` function. There is a check in the body `if (!any(is.element(class(f), c("mforecast", "forecast", "ts", "integer", "numeric", "Arima", "ets", "lm", "bats", "tbats", "nnetar", "stlm"))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forecast object is just a list containing a few items, and given a class "forecast". Look at any of the existing functions to see how to do it. Here is a very simple template:

```
myfun <- function(x, h, ...)
{
  # Compute some forecasts
  fc <- ....
  # Construct output list
  output <- list(mean=fc, x=x, ...)
  # Return with forecasting class
  return(structure(output, class='forecast'))
}
```