# adding a custom forecast function that extends snaive

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, random-walk

I would like to extend `snaive` from the `forecast` package (or maybe `lagwalk`?) and add a custom forecast function `custom_snaive`.

I would like it to get as a parameter a list of desired_lags and forecast a simple average of their values. E.g. for hourly data, the following call: `custom_snaive(lags=c(24, 48, 24*7))` would return a simple average of the values from 1 day ago, 2 days ago and a week ago.

How would you go about implementing such a function? should I rewrite snaive and use lagwalk? I do not care about prediction intervals currently.

(related to [How to create a forecast object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398460/how-to-create-a-forecast-object-in-r) but simpler)

Answer (score 0):

I've followed the [baggedModel](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/baggedModel.R) example. I called `lagwalk` for every lag and then tricked `forecast` to think that this is a `baggedModel`, as it's pretty similar (only it's just aggregation, no bootstrapping here). Would appreciate a code review by someone who knows the `forecast` package, is there anything simpler I could have used?

```
historical_mean_model <- function(y, lags, lambda=NULL, biasadj=FALSE, ..., x=y) {
  out <- list()
  out$y <- as.ts(y)
  out$modelargs <- list(...)
  out$models <- lapply(lags, function(lag) {
    mod <- forecast:::lagwalk(
      x, lag = lag, drift = FALSE,
      lambda = lambda, biasadj = biasadj, ...
    )
  })
  fitted_all_lags <- lapply(out$models, fitted)
  fitted_all_lags <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(fitted_all_lags))
  out$fitted <- ts(apply(fitted_all_lags, 1, mean))
  tsp(out$fitted) <- tsp(out$y)
  out$residuals <- out$y - out$fitted

  out$series <- deparse(substitute(y))
  out$method <- "historical_mean_model"

  out$call <- match.call()
  return(structure(out, class = c("baggedModel")))
}
```